# Add counter value in Windows cmd script

Tags: windows, command-line

My script goes similar to this:

```
cd <Directory>
set counter = 1
for /r %%f in (*) do (
<Do task>
echo Task completed for file<counter> >> C:\log
counter++
)
```

I can't figure out how to use the actual `counter` value. If i use `counter` or `%counter%` it simply echoes the same string. How should i modify the `counter` lines in this case?

Answer (score 7):

`SET` must be used with `/A` if you want to evaluate mathematical expressions. You also need to enable Delayed Expansion first by typing `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` as the first line. Evaluation inside `**FOR**` loop is not done until the last iteration happens. But I modified the batch file so that the value of Counter is incremented in each iteration.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

@echo off

set /a counter=1

for /r %%f in (*) do (
  echo Task Completed for file !counter! >> c:\log
  set /a counter=!counter!+1
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the loop, but not sure about `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION`. When i tried it, it says `Access is Denied`

Answer (score 0):

SET /A Variable_Number Math_symbol = Step(s)

> `set /a Var_Num+=1` -> Num_Var = Num_Var + 1 (Step)
>
> `set /a Var_Num-=1` -> Num_Var = Num_Var - 1 (Step)
>
> `set /a Var_Num*=2` -> Num_Var = Num_Var x 2 (Steps)
>
> `set /a Var_Num/=2` -> Num_Var = Num_Var : 2 (Steps)

In a Loop:

```
@echo off
set counter=0
:start-loop

set /a counter+=1

echo %counter% times... 
:: or/and
echo %counter% times... >> %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\log.txt

timeout /t 1 >nul
goto :start-loop
```

Your example: (in 'FOR' loop)

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
@echo off
set /a counter=1

for /r %%f in (*) do (
  echo Task Completed for file !counter! >> C:\log.txt
  echo Path to File: [ %%f ] >> C:\log.txt
  set /a counter+=1
)
```